# After calling NHibernate.Initialize(proxyObject) I'm getting wrong objectType

Tags: nhibernate, proxy-classes

I have object hierarchy Parent->Child
(Lazy loading is set to true by default)
Now I'm loading all Parent objects from database. All child object will have the type ChildProxyGUID.

then I write the

```
IList<Parent> parentList = NHibernateHelper.List<Parent>();
foreach(Parent parent in parentList)
{
  if(!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(parent.Child))
  {
    NHibernateUtil.Initialize(parent.Child);
    if(parent.Child.GetType() != typeof(Child)) //parent.Child.GetType() return me proxy type
      throw new ArgumentException("wrong type");
  }
}
```

How can I convert parent.Child to Real type "Child". I need the real type (Child) because of system checking.
This example is simple in real life I have a very complicated mappings and relations.

Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
var realObject = session.GetSessionImplementation()
                        .PersistenceContext.Unproxy(parent.Child)
```

However, it's a bad a idea to have your code rely on this type of checks, as it violates the [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), creating code that is harder to maintain.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you about LSP. So I've did some changes in the core, and now it's working with Proxy classes. Thanks